# JPA: Persisting ManyToOne entities correctly

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa, hibernate-mapping

I've been looking for over a week for a fix to my issue but without getting any clear results although it seems to be a basic issue.
Please let me know if I'm doing anything wrong or I have some misunderstanding.

**Here is the situation:**

A user connects to the platform to make Transactions.
So I have a many to one relationship between the User and Transaction entities. 
(a User make many Transactions, and every transaction is made by only one user)

The idea is that when I persist a new "Transaction", the UserId of the current user of the platform goes as a foreign key to the Transaction table.

**The problem is:**

1. when I try to persist a new "Transaction", a new "User" is also
   created with a new UserId.
2. I don't find how to get correctly the ID of the current user to add
   it in the Transaction table

**Here is my code:**

The Transaction entity:

```
@Entity
public class Transaction implements Serializable{

@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
int idTransaction;

@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.MERGE)
@JoinColumn(name="FK_User")
User    user;

}
```

The User entity:

```
@Entity
public class User implements Serializable{

int idUser;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="user")
Set<Transaction>    transactions;   
}
```

My method doTransaction from the ManagedBean:

```
public String doTransaction(){

    String navigateTo="/pages/expediteur/succes";

    transaction.setExpediteur(expediteur);
    transactionServiceLocal.updateTransaction(transaction);

    return  navigateTo;
}
```

Hope I have been clear and brief in my explanation.

*** EDIT ***

Thank you for help, I have tried to implement the solutions mentionned in the comments, but now I'm getting this error:

```
ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-46) Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
```

and when I add those lines to my code:

```
System.out.println("The current user is "+user.getIdUser());
System.out.println("Your current transaction is "+user.getIdTransaction());
```

I'm getting 0 for all the entities as a return.

I think my problem is getting correctly to my entities stocked in the Database.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have access to the user ID:

```
public Transaction createAndPersistTransaction(Long userId) {
    // get a reference to the given user:
    User user = em.getReference(User.class, userId);
    // create a transaction
    Transaction tx = new Transaction();
    // set its user:
    tx.setUser(user);
    // persist it
    em.persist(tx);
    return tx;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for help, I have tried to implement the solutions mentionned in the comments, but now I'm getting this error:

ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-46) Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails 
and when I add those lines to my code:

System.out.println("The current user is "+user.getIdUser());
System.out.println("Your current transaction is "+user.getIdTransaction());
I'm getting 0 for all the entities as a return.

I think my problem is getting correctly to my entities stocked in the Database.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the User should have an @Id and you can set the `cascade = CascadeType.ALL` on  the `one-to-many` side):

```
@Entity
public class User implements Serializable{

    @Id
    Integer idUser;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    Set<Transaction> transactions = new HashSet()<>;   
}
```

Now you must have a `userId` sent from the UI, so you have to fetch the User first:

```
User user = em.getReference(User.class, userId);
```

You can create a Transaction and assign both sides of the associations:

```
Transaction tx = new Transaction();
tx.setUser(user);
user.getTransactions().add(tx);
em.flush();
```

The `Transaction` will be saved automatically, once it gets associated to `User` entity.

Comment: Thank you for help, I have tried to implement the solutions mentionned in the comments, but now I'm getting this error:

ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-46) Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails 
and when I add those lines to my code:

System.out.println("The current user is "+user.getIdUser());
System.out.println("Your current transaction is "+user.getIdTransaction());
I'm getting 0 for all the entities as a return.
I think my problem is getting correctly to my entities stocked in the Database.